# Meaning of "more important"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Meaning of ***creep*** in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/creep) is

> someone who tries to make someone ***more important*** like them by being very polite and helpful in a way that is not sincere

What is the meaning of "more important" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [relevant definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/important) of important is:

> (of a person) having high rank or status.

This could be a boss (as it is in Cambridge's example), a politician, or a celebrity, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It means they want someone they admire or respect to like them, usually in order to betray them, or take advantage of them in some way.

Comment: "more important" probably means someone like a boss or at a higher political level.